# How do I make Steam sort my games in alphabetical order?

Tags: steam

Somehow, I just got Steam to  sort my games in reverse alphabetical order.  I don't like that.

How can I undo it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Over your games, there's a tiny word "Games" denoting the grid column.  Click on it.

[image]

Comment: I was curious as to how you did that because I use Detail View and I couldn't get it **out** of alphabetical order.

Comment: @OrigamiRobot Heheh yeah after linking this in chat, I quickly found out that there are more views than just list view.  :P